# Text Stuck in Message Field

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

Using an iPhone 4 and within Messages, a previously sent message text is stuck within the text box!

Whenever I open a new message window, the text box shows with the old message text pre-populated within it and I have to delete the text and then type out my message.

Even for SMS replies, the message field shows the old text always and I am having to delete it manually in order to type a new one.

This is happening with iMessage ON and OFF and I have restarted the phone as well as reset it from an iTunes backup but still the issue persists.

Is there away way I can erase the text permanently so that I get a blank message field when I send a new sms?

Comment: I have a friend with this exact same issue. Have you found a solution? Tried:
Deleting the original video (Hers shows a video she sent prior)
Deleting the text/iMessage that was sent with the video.
Rebooting phone
Turning off iMessage Have not tried, but saw something while reading...
Delete the entire conversation from the person the original text was from. Again, I've not tried this, but maybe it would help.

Comment: I am having same problem. Needing a solution. Don't understand how this forwarded message is still there.

Answer (score -2):

Had a similar "stuck in message" problem. Powering off/powering on fixed the issue....

Comment: The OP specifically stated this didn't work, nor a restore.